# Java: How to convert list to set then compare for missing values

Tags: java, list, set, java-stream

My goal is to locate and print any missing values in my data using the Set
interface.

I have a POJO like below

```
public class Info {

    private final String folder;
    private final String version;
    private final String key;
        
    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }
    
    public static Builder builder(Info info) {
        return new Builder(info);
    }
        
    private Info(Builder builder) {
        this.folder = builder.folder;
        this.version = builder.version;
        this.key = builder.key;
        
    public String getFolder() {
        return folder;
    }
        
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
        
    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
        
    // toString(), hashCode(), equals()
        
    // Builder class
        
    public Builder withFolder(String folder){
        this.folder = folder;
        return this;
    }

   // withVersion(String version)
   // withKey(String key)


    public Info build(){
        return new Info(this);    
    }

}
```

Using the below code, I create a list from my data source.

```
List<Info> newList = previousList.stream().map(m -> Info.builder()
            .withFolder(m.getFolder())
            .withKey(m.getKey())
            .withVersion(m.getVersion())
            .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Printed output is below
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Below is output similar to my list output.
Two example folders and two example missing files are shown.
For each key, there are multiple version numbers.

```
// Output

[folder=folderA, version=3.48.137, key=fileA-sources.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.128, key=fileA-sources.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.125, key=fileA-sources.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.137, key=fileA-javadoc.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.128, key=fileA-javadoc.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.125, key=fileA-javadoc.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.137, key=fileA.jar]
[folder=folderA, version=3.48.128, key=fileA.jar]

// Missing [folder=folderA, version= 3.48.125, key=fileA.jar]

[folder=folderB, version=1.7.16, key=fileB.pom]
[folder=folderB, version=1.7.14, key=fileB.pom]
[folder=folderB, version=1.7.12, key=fileB.pom]
[folder=folderB, version=1.7.16, key=fileB.jar]
[folder=folderB, version=1.7.14, key=fileB.jar]

// Missing [folder=folderB, version 1.7.12, key=fileB.jar]
```

Below is my stream to convert the list into a set.

```
Set<Info> set = list.stream().map(m -> Info.builder()
            .withFolder(m.getFolderKey())
            .withVersion(m.getVersion())
            .withKey(m.getKey())
            .build()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

My goal is to locate and print any missing values in my data using a Set. Specifically the version numbers.

I want to compare the version numbers that are part of fileA-sources.jar, fileA-javadoc.jar, and fileA.jar in order to find any that are missing. See above Output for a commented example of a missing entry.

My data contains seven different file types and there are many similar entries to the two above.

I'm pretty new to Java and most likely missing some very elementary things. I realize that my plan may be completely off, so any help or a point in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have shown the output of the processing, but without the input, it is hard to understand what you are wanting.  Can you add the input to your question as well?

Comment: I added the input and would like to identify any missing version numbers among keys fileA.ext1, fileA.ext2, et al. fileA.ext1 and fileA.ext2 are supposed to have exactly the same amount of versions and corresponding keys. So, my aim is to locate missing versions.

Comment: We don’t know anything about your `Object` and `SetObject` classes. What’s striking, is that you seem to have two different classes for the same thing. Further, naming your own class `Object` is a bad idea. Then, when I read the sentence “To recap: I'd like to compare Sets of keys and version numbers for any missing keys and version numbers”, I was surprised. You didn’t say anything about that requirement before, so “recap” doesn’t fit. In fact, the long winded stuff before that sentences doesn’t seem to be relevant to your actual task at all.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll work on clarifying my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not fully baked, but it does seem to work.

1: Collect a set of keys from the actual entries

2: Collect a set of folder/version combinations from the actual entries

3: Build a set desired entries using combinations of collected keys and folder/version combinations

4: Filter-out actual entries from desired entries

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
    Set<FolderEntry> findMissing(Set<FolderEntry> actual) {
        Set<String> keys = actual.stream().map(e -> e.key).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Set<FolderEntry> folderVersions = actual.stream()
                .map(e -> new FolderEntry(e.folder, e.version, null))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Set<FolderEntry> missing = folderVersions.stream()
                .flatMap(fv -> {
                    Stream.Builder<FolderEntry> builder = Stream.builder();
                    keys.forEach(key -> builder.accept(new FolderEntry(fv.folder, fv.version, key)));
                    return builder.build();
                })
                .filter(desired -> !actual.contains(desired))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
        return missing;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<FolderEntry> folderAEntries = Set.of(
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.137", "fileA-sources.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.128", "fileA-sources.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.125", "fileA-sources.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.137", "fileA-javadoc.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.128", "fileA-javadoc.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.125", "fileA-javadoc.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.137", "fileA.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderA", "3.48.128", "fileA.jar")
                );
        new Test().findMissing(folderAEntries)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        Set<FolderEntry> folderBEntries = Set.of(
                new FolderEntry("folderB", "1.7.16", "fileB.pom"),
                new FolderEntry("folderB", "1.7.14", "fileB.pom"),
                new FolderEntry("folderB", "1.7.12", "fileB.pom"),
                new FolderEntry("folderB", "1.7.16", "fileB.jar"),
                new FolderEntry("folderB", "1.7.14", "fileB.jar")
                );
        new Test().findMissing(folderBEntries)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static class FolderEntry {
        final String folder;
        final String version;
        final String key;

        public FolderEntry(String folder, String version, String key) {
            this.folder = folder;
            this.version = version;
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(folder, key, version);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            FolderEntry other = (FolderEntry) obj;
            return Objects.equals(folder, other.folder) && Objects.equals(key, other.key)
                    && Objects.equals(version, other.version);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FolderInfo [folder=" + folder + ", version=" + version + ", key=" + key + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FolderInfo [folder=folderA, version=3.48.125, key=fileA.jar]
FolderInfo [folder=folderB, version=1.7.12, key=fileB.jar]
```

---

*I misunderstood your problem in the beginning and my initial answer was not helpful.  I'm leaving it here for history:*

If you already have a `List<SetObject>`, then you can obtain a `Set<SetObject>` by simply passing the list as an argument to the constructor for the Set implementation

```
Set<SetObject> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

If you can futher explain the logic behind determining if something is missing I may be able to help further.

Comment: Yes. So, for example, fileA.jar, fileA.pom. fileA.properties (there may be more files depending on the folder) are all supposed to have the same version numbers. There are multiple version numbers per file, eg 1.2-2.1. An example of a missing file may be key: fileA.jar, version: 1.4. I would like to way to identify any version numbers that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to `generate a full set` based on known pattern. After, iterate through initial list and remove form `full_generated_set` similar elements. What remains in `full_generated_set` are `missing elements`.

```
public class TestFolder {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //initial set
        List<FolderData> list = new ArrayList<FolderData>();
        list.add(new FolderData("folderB", "1.7.16", "fileB.pom"));
        list.add(new FolderData("folderB", "1.7.14", "fileB.pom"));
        list.add(new FolderData("folderB", "1.7.12", "fileB.pom"));
        list.add(new FolderData("folderB", "1.7.16", "fileB.jar"));
        list.add(new FolderData("folderB", "1.7.14", "fileB.jar"));
        
        List<String> requiredPattern = new ArrayList<String>();
        requiredPattern.add("pom");
        requiredPattern.add("jar");
        
        Set<String> set = list.stream().filter(t->t.folder.equals("folderB")).
                          map(t->t.version).distinct().
                          collect(Collectors.toSet());
        set.forEach(System.out::println);
        
        //create a full set
        Set<FolderData> fullSet = new HashSet<FolderData>();
        for(String version: set)
        {
            for(String pattern: requiredPattern)
            {
              fullSet.add(new FolderData("folderB",version,"fileB."+pattern));
            }
        }
        
        fullSet.forEach(System.out::println);
        //remove matching elements
        for(FolderData fd:list)
        {
            FolderData remove=null;
            for(FolderData haveFd:fullSet)
            {
                if(fd.folder.equals(haveFd.folder) && fd.version.equals(haveFd.version) && fd.key.equals(haveFd.key))
                {
                    remove = haveFd;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if(remove!=null) fullSet.remove(remove);
        }
        System.out.println("missing");
        fullSet.forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }
    
    static class FolderData
    {
        String folder;
        String version;
        String key;
        
        public FolderData(String folder, String version, String key)
        {
            this.folder = folder;
            this.version = version;
            this.key = key;
        }
        
        public String toString()
        {
            return folder+","+version+","+key;
        }
    }
}
```

An enhancement can be to update `requiredPattern`, so it's not needed to add manually cases.

```
requiredPattern =list.stream().map(t->t.key).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
//also update on generating full set to use the new pattern
fullSet.add(new FolderData("folderB",version,pattern));
```

Output

```
//version
1.7.16
1.7.14
1.7.12
//full generated set
folderB,1.7.12,fileB.pom
folderB,1.7.12,fileB.jar
folderB,1.7.16,fileB.jar
folderB,1.7.16,fileB.pom
folderB,1.7.14,fileB.pom
folderB,1.7.14,fileB.jar
//missing
folderB,1.7.12,fileB.jar
```